# Not showing git info Codelens in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, codelens

## In my Visual Studio Community 2022, Codelens doesn't show options related to git.

**Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > CodeLens**

**My visaul studio doesn't have these options.**

- Show Timeline (Git)
- Show Authors & Changes (Git)

[Not show this options (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqOb8.png)

**It shows "0 references" on classes and methods but not "git changes and author"(0 changes | 0 authors)**

```cs
    0 refernces // but not show => 0 changes | 0 authors
    public void HelloWord()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello Word");
    }
```

[my problem here (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKa6x.png)

#### I want it to be so.

[I want it here (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnbUY.png)

```cs
    0 refernces | 0 changes | 0 authors
    public void HelloWord()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello Word");
    }
```

**Question :** What do I have to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature is available in `Visual Studio 2022 Professional`, and some features are not supported in the `community` version.

Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > CodeLens

[image]

Comment:  well, that sucks. I have an enterprise license, but just don't want to install it on all PCs. I'll start using VSCode.

Comment: I have Enterprise on only one machine, same problem as above.